# Manipulating with TCComponentBOMLIne in Teamcenter

Tags: java, teamcenter, teamcenter-soa

I'm working with Teamcenter using the Java SOA API.
**How can I remove the child line from the structure correctly?**

Here is my code:

```
TCComponentBOMLine bl = bomWin.setWindowTopLine(***); // ROOT BOMLine
        
AIFComponentContext[] ctxes = bl.getChildren();
for (AIFComponentContext ctx : ctxes) {
    TCComponentBOMLine child = (TCComponentBOMLine)ctx.getComponent();
    bl.remove("bl_all_child_lines", child);
    bl.save();
}
bl.save();
bl.refresh();
bomWin.save();
bomWin.refresh();
```

After that, I'm adding new child lines for structure.

In the RAC all is good, but in console I see an **ICCTException**:

```
com.teamcenter.soaictstubs.ICCTException: - Wrong sign
    at com.teamcenter.soaictstubs.ICCT.getProperty(Unknown Source)
```

What's wrong?